# Error while removing fragment containing videoView in 4.0.4

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-videoview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, illegalstateexception

I have a fragment containing VideoView and few other views.

```
public class PlayerPane extends Fragment { 
    ... // static variables
    private ImageView imageView;
    private ImageView gifView;
    private VideoView videoView;
    private WebView webView;
    private PDFView pdfView;
    private MyScrollTextView scrollTextView;
    private MediaPlayer audioPlayer;
    ...

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        if (videoView != null && videoView.isPlaying()) {
            LOGGER.info("Stopping videoView");
            videoView.stopPlayback();
            videoView.suspend();
            videoView = null;
        }
        super.onDestroyView();
    }
```

Whenever I remove this fragment while the video is being played, IllegalStateException is being thrown only in Android 4.0.4 (No issue with versions above 4.0.4).

Following is the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at android.media.MediaPlayer._reset(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaPlayer.reset(MediaPlayer.java:1236)
    at android.widget.VideoView.release(VideoView.java:549)
    at android.widget.VideoView.access$2300(VideoView.java:49)
    at android.widget.VideoView$6.surfaceDestroyed(VideoView.java:537)
    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:581)
    at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:290)
    at android.view.View.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(View.java:9823)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewGroup.java:2266)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:3588)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeViewInternal(ViewGroup.java:3568)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.removeView(ViewGroup.java:3516)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:951)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeFragment(FragmentManager.java:1123)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:592)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1382)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
```

This is how I remove the fragment:

```
getFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragmentToBeRemoved).commit();
```

What is causing this IllegalStateException and how do I resolve this? 
Anything pointing towards the solution would be of great help.

Comment: why you are removing fragment, I mean you can simply replace with other fragment

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] to hope finding a specific answer of your problem. Here, we only have the destroy part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you take a different approach. Before you remove the fragment. Call this code before you attempt to remove the fragment.

```
videoView.stopPlayback();
videoView.suspend();
```

As is evident from the stack trace, when you remove the fragment, What Android does is to remove the VideoView (it's a view after all) which results in Videoview Attempting to release the underlying Mediaplayer. But the Mediaplayer itself might not be a state to be released which is causing this issue. Ideally this well might have been handled within VideocView, but looks like no

Comment: I have already tried stopPlayback and suspend, but they do not help. These are called within the onDestroyView of Fragment. Are you suggesting me to call these methods outside of onDestroyView?

Comment: Yes, I am suggesting you to call them outside of destroView. Call them before you do this `getFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(fragmentToBeRemoved).commit();`   The difference is that instead of someone down the line cleaning up the resources, you are doing them explicitly in a order. Robust systems anyways are designed to handle such cases but somehow in this case it does not. give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I think you call reset() after release() and this throw illegalstateexception.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I'm not doing that explicitly. Also, I face the above described issue only with 4.0.4 and not any version above.

Answer (score 0):

See the code given on this URL. This is from the actual android github repo.
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/866658261f4613e17ed6f39a74975ad0c9f40767/media/jni/android_media_MediaPlayer.cpp

the reset function from java calls the native _reset function which is given in the CPP file in this URL this is very hard to debug as it is a JNI calls which can not be debugged. So In my opinion it is very hard to know what is going wrong unless we really know what exactly you are doing

Comment: I have added precise detail on what I am doing. The above issue occurs only with 4.0.4 and not any version above. Have not tested for version below. But please let me know if more detail needs to be added, will delightedly do so. My priority is to resolve the issue.